# One versus rest classifier

Tags: machine-learning, classification, svm

I'm implementing an **one-versus-rest** classifier to discriminate between neural data corresponding (1) to moving a computer cursor up and (2) to moving it in any of the other seven cardinal directions or no movement. I'm using an SVM classifier with an RBF kernel (created by LIBSVM), and I did a grid search to find the best possible gamma and cost parameters for my classifier. I have tried using training data with 338 elements from each of the two classes (undersampling my large "rest" class) and have used 338 elements from my first class and 7218 from my second one with a weighted SVM.

I have also used feature selection to bring the number of features I'm using down from 130 to 10. I tried using the ten "best" features and the ten "worst" features when training my classifier. I have also used the entire feature set.

Unfortunately, my results are not very good, and moreover, I cannot find an explanation why. I tested with 37759 data points, where 1687 of them came from the "one" (i.e. "up") class and the remaining 36072 came from the "rest" class. In all cases, my classifier is 95% accurate BUT the values that are predicted correctly all fall into the "rest" class (i.e. all my data points are predicted as "rest" and all the values that are incorrectly predicted fall in the "one"/"up" class). When I tried testing with 338 data points from each class (the same ones I used for training), I found that the number of support vectors was 666, which is ten less than the number of data points. In this case, the percent accuracy is only 71%, which is unusual since my training and testing data are the exact same.

Do you have any idea what could be going wrong? If you have any suggestions, please let me know.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm a bit confused, because a high number of support vector is often synonymous of overfitting, but on the other hand, if your training and testing data set are identical, overfitting should give 100% accuracy... Could you manually fix C to a value tht forces overfitting (I can't remember is it's C=0 or C=infinity) and tell us the results? The other thing that confuses me is, if you use LibSVM, how do you manage to do a one-versus-rest classifier? Because it's seems that the authors opted for a 1v1 approach (http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/faq.html#f419)

Answer (score 1):

Test dataset being same as training data implies your training accuracy was 71%. There is nothing wrong about it as the data was possibly not well separable by the kernel you used.
However, one point of concern is the number of support vectors being high suggests probable overfitting .

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this amounts to an answer - it would probably be hard to give one without actually seeing the data - but here are some ideas regarding the issue you describe:

1. In general, SVM tries to find a hyperplane that would best separate your classes. However, since you have opted for 1vs1 classification, you have no choice but to mix all negative cases together (your 'rest' class). This might make the 'best' separation much less fit to solve your problem. I'm guessing that this might be a major issue here. 
   To verify if that's the case, I suggest trying to use only one other cardinal direction as the negative set, and see if that improves results. In case it does, you can train 7 classifiers, one for each direction. Another option might be to use the multiclass option of libSVM, or a tool like [SVMLight](http://svmlight.joachims.org/svm_multiclass.html), which is able to classify one against many.
2. One caveat of most SVM implementations is their inability to support big differences between the positive and negative sets, even with weighting. From my experience, weighting factors of over 4-5 are problematic in many cases. On the other hand, since your variety in the negative side is large, taking equal sizes might also be less than optimal. Thus, I'd suggest using something like 338 positive examples, and around 1000-1200 random negative examples, with weighting.
3. A little off your question, I would have considered also other types of classification. To start with, I'd suggest thinking about [knn](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-nearest_neighbor_algorithm).

Hope it helps :)